# Java REST Enum serialization and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, enums

In a REST api using **Spring MVC** , if I want to restrict the string values that can be passed as a http GET request argument to one of the following

valueA
valueB

I think I should use an Enum type in java.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    @JsonProperty("valueA")
    VALUE_A("valueA"),
    @JsonProperty("valueB")
    VALUE_B("valueB");

    private final String label;

    private MyEnum(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    
    @Override 
    public String toString() { 
        return this.label; 
    }
    
    @JsonValue
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

This however only handles serialization of the Enum. When I receive `valueA` as a requestParam in a spring controller, there is a `ConversionFailedException` because

I have read the following article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-enum-request-param but my question is , **is there a simpler solution than to write a custom converter.**

I would not want to write and register a converter for each of the enums I want to exchange in my REST api.

I have also tried this but the forValue does not seem to be called by spring mvc to deserialize the arguments .

public enum MyEnum {

```
VALUE_A("valueA"),
VALUE_B("valueB");

private final String label;

private MyEnum(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

@Override 
public String toString() { 
    return this.label; 
}

@JsonValue
public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

@JsonCreator
public MyEnum forValue(String label) {
            
        for (MyEnum enum: MyEnum .values()) {
            if (enum.getLabel().equals(label)) {
                return enum;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find MyEnum Enum to match :" + label);
    }
```

}

Comment: This probably is possible with a regular class/Bean object, but you are dealing with an Enum here, so I would guess you need to do a custom converter.

Comment: Have you considered using `@JsonCreator` on a custom method to perform the deserialization?

Comment: I have added to the question my example with @JsonCreator but it is not called by Spring MVC.. to deserialize RequestParam arguments.. .. I suppose that makes sense since arguments are Strings and not json... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a converter you can of course fall back to Spring's [StringToEnumConverterFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToEnumConverterFactory.java) that requires you to send the Enum literals literally - so in your case `VALUE_A` or `VALUE_B`. You only need a more sophisticated converter if you decide to identify your Enum by any other value than their literal but please be aware that the approach of having your own converter has it's caveats as well as we see in your example because in contrast to the Enum literal (that gets checked by the compiler to be unique) e. g. your value *don't* has to be unique, like in your example where both literals have the value "valueA", therefore a mapping wouldn't be distinct.